# How to remove post view count

Tags: css, post-meta

My theme shows the post view count. There are no options in the settings to disable post view counter meta.

Can anyone help me to remove that post views count? I want to hide it from visitors.

Please help. I am not a pro user, so kindly give easy steps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to use inspection tools - like "Inspect" on Google Chrome, or Firebug on Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

If, as you say, the theme does not provide direct show/hide configuration options, your most typical choices will be, I think:

1) If the theme provides a CSS class enabling targeting of the view count as rendered, to make it disappear via CSS;

2) If the theme provides a filter for rendering the view count, make it disappear with a custom function;

3) Edit as many of the template files as necessary, with the relevant code removed or replaced.

Though, in the case of #1, you might be able to achieve the effect with an independent CSS processor (like JetPack Edit CSS, for example), it's best practice to perform alterations in a **child theme**, so as to avoid losing them during upgrades, and (as is seldom noted!), if you are going to perform multiple customizations over time, to keep them organized and set apart in one place.

Answer (score 0):

In my case just:

```
.entry-views-count{
       display: none !important;
   }
```

in style.css was enough.